# Android DatePicker Dialog limit min year and max year

Tags: java, android

I've been battling with a part of my code for a while to put age restriction on the datepickerdialog but it is not working i've researched but none of the solution seems to work. Here is my code so far:

```
EditText birthdate=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_birth);
    public void getdate() {
        final Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                    int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                updateLabel();
            }

        };
        birthdate.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    new DatePickerDialog(Register.this, date, myCalendar
                            .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar
                            .get(Calendar.MONTH), myCalendar
                            .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();

                }
                return true;
            }
        });

    }

    private void updateLabel() {

        String myFormat = "MM/dd/yy";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);
        final Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        birthdate.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should look like this

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mDateDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateDisplay);
    mPickDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickDate);

    mPickDate.setOnClickListener(this);

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    maxYear = mYear - 7;
    maxMonth = mMonth;
    maxDay = mDay;

    minYear = mYear - 18;
    minMonth = mMonth;
    minDay = mDay;

    // display the current date (this method is below)
    updateDisplay(maxYear, maxMonth, maxDay);

}

private void updateDisplay(int year, int month, int day) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mDateDisplay.setText(new StringBuilder()
            // Month is 0 based so add 1
            .append(month + 1).append("-").append(day).append("-")
            .append(year).append(" "));

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);

}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
        /*
         * mYear = year; 
         * mMonth = monthOfYear; 
         * mDay = dayOfMonth;
         */
        // updateDisplay();



        if (year > maxYear ||monthOfYear > maxMonth && year == maxYear||
                 dayOfMonth > maxDay && year == maxYear && monthOfYear == maxMonth){

            view.updateDate(maxYear, maxMonth, maxDay);
            updateDisplay(maxYear, maxMonth, maxDay);

        }
        else if (year < minYear ||monthOfYear < minMonth && year == minYear||
                 dayOfMonth < minDay && year == minYear && monthOfYear == minMonth) {

            view.updateDate(minYear, minMonth, minDay);
            updateDisplay(minYear, minMonth, minDay);
        }
        else {

            view.updateDate(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
            updateDisplay(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
        } 

    }
};

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, mYear - 7,
                mMonth, mDay);
    }
    return null;
}
 }
```